# Confusion with function pointer, __cdecl, and template

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, function-pointers, cdecl

In Visual Studio 2019, I have written the following test codes, but the results confused me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T, class Func>
int call(T x, Func f) { return f(x); }

int square(int x) { return x * x; }

int main() {

    int (*func0) (int) = square; // line 0, OK
    //int (func1)(int) = square; // line 1, wrong

    int (__cdecl *func1) (int)  = square; // line 2, OK
    //int (__cdecl func2)(int) = square; // line 3, wrong

    cout << ((int(__cdecl*)(int)) square)(5) << endl; // line 4, OK
    //cout << ((int(__cdecl)(int)) square)(5) << endl; // line 5, wrong

    cout << call<int, int (*)(int)>(5, square) << endl; // line 6, OK
    //cout << call<int, int ()(int)>(5, square) << endl; // line 7, wrong

    cout << call<int, int(__cdecl*)(int)>(5, square) << endl; // line 8, OK
    cout << call<int, int(__cdecl)(int)>(5, square) << endl; // line 9, OK

    return 0;
}
```

(I am aware that I can omit the types when using `call`, but this is an experiment.)

I thought I was able to understand everything from line 0 to line 7. What I had in mind is that `square` is a funtion pointer, so it should have type `int (*) (int)` or perhaps `int(__cdecl*) (int)`, and these two are either identical or can be casted to each other (I didn't change the calling convention of the project, so the default is `__cdecl`).

However, I was surprised that both line 8 and line 9 compile and run correctly. Why does this happen?

By comparing lines 6, 7 with lines 8, 9, I think the problem comes from adding `__cdecl`, but in [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/cdecl?view=vs-2019) nothing like this is mentioned.

---

I then printed out the types:

```
    // ...
    cout << typeid(square).name() << endl; // output: int __cdecl(int)
    cout << typeid(*square).name() << endl; // output: int __cdecl(int)
    cout << typeid(&square).name() << endl; // output: int(__cdecl*)(int)

    cout << (typeid(square) == typeid(int(*) (int))) << endl; // output: false
    cout << (typeid(square) == typeid(int(__cdecl) (int))) << endl; // output: true
    cout << (typeid(square) == typeid(int(__cdecl*) (int))) << endl; // output: false

    cout << (typeid(square) == typeid(*square)) << endl; // output: true
    // ...
```

It seems that `square` indeed has type `int (__cdecl) (int)`. Also, I don't understand why `square` and `*square` are of the same type...

Could someone explain these phenomena to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`square` and `*square` are the same type because functions decay, just like arrays do, to pointers, except (just like arrays) under certain contexts. In particular, decay is suppressed under `typeid` and `&`, but not under `*`, so `typeid(square)` gives you the type of `square`, `int (__cdecl)(int)`, while `typeid(*square)` means `typeid(*&square)` means `typeid(square)` gives the same thing. This leads to the odd fact that you can write as many `*`s as you want and they will all do nothing: `*************square` is the same as `square`.

Now, to the rest of your question, you wrote the type "function taking `int` returning `int`" wrong. `int ()(int)` means "function taking no arguments returning function taking `int` returning `int`". You wanted `int(int)`. Then this works:

```
cout << call<int, int(int)>(5, square) << "\n"; // line 7, fixed (FYI: endl is not normally necessary)
```

Because now `call` has arguments list `(int x, int f(int))`, and a parameter declaration of function type is automatically adjusted to have pointer to function type, making `call<int, int(int)>` functionally identical to `call<int, int (*)(int)>`. (This does not work for variable declarations or casts, so lines 1, 3, 5 remain incorrect.) The extra parentheses caused the type to be misinterpreted. Line 9 works because putting `__cdecl` inside the parentheses makes them not be misinterpreted (instead of being the function declarator, they become grouping symbols).

```
cout << call<int, int (__cdecl)(int)>(5, square) << "\n"; // line 9, OK
```

Again, the type of `call`'s parameter is adjusted. `int (__cdecl f)(int)` becomes `int (__cdecl *f)(int)`, which makes line 9 functionally identical to line 8.

Comment: I see, it's a decay that I was not aware of. Now I understand all the logic here. But still it is a wierd thing that `*************square == square` ... Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error with the line:

```
int (func1)(int) = square; // line 1, wrong
```

is that you are missing a '*', it needs to be:

```
int (*func1)(int) = square; // line 1, wrong
```

same with

```
//int (__cdecl func2)(int) = square; // line 3, wrong

cout << ((int(__cdecl)(int)) square)(5) << endl; // line 5, wrong
```

needs to be

```
cout << ((int(__cdecl*)(int)) square)(5) << endl; // line 5, wrong
```

Comment: Yes, this is the grammar that I understood. I intentionally put these wrong lines for comparison. My main question is, why is line 9 OK?